# Why does Google document show size Zero when using Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I was fetching file from google drive using API google document files size shows

zero. But Ms-Word files size shows as usual. What I need to do google document file act as a word file.

Comment: I wonder, where do you see that? The following program http://valtih1978.github.io/VisualDict/almende-vis.html seems to display the size correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Native Google files (Docs, Spreadsheets, Slides and Forms) do not count against a user's storage quota and thus show as zero bytes via the API. Google does not expose actual storage usage of these native files but you can get an approximation by [exporting the file](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export) and checking the download size.

Comment: Thanks jay.I was tried this success but no response body.What i have to give mime-type if file is document ....?

Comment: If you have questions about how to export files, that really belongs in a separate post.

Comment: I think so.But i totally messed up.

Comment: Is there any way to get download URL for Native Google Files(not export links)  using  file.get .Becouse i need to upload those files to other drives like drop-box